# Constrain Table Search to Certain Dynamic Key Values in Javascript ArrayObjects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter

I am creating a custom search and I have an array of objects.

```
const data = [{
    name: "Janet McKenly",
    age: 49,
    city: "Baltimore",
    active: "2019-02-15",
    role: "Admin. Assistant"
  },
  {
    name: "Eric Brown",
    age: 23,
    city: "Dallas",
    active: "2020-06-01",
    role: "Janitor"
  },
  {
    name: "Nora Payne",
    age: 41,
    city: "Los Angeles",
    active: "2020-10-02",
    role: "Sales Associate"
  }
]
```

I have another array that is dynamically created that allows only for the specific parameters to search in.

```
let searchColumnOnlyArray = ["name", "city", "active"]; // (generated dynamically)
```

`role` & `age` should not be searchable.

The goal is to only search values for keys set in `searchColumnOnlyArray`.

I am able to filter by hardcoding a name parameter ["name"] but the `searchColumnOnlyArray` is dynamic and will change... below is the method I am using:

```
searchTable(term: any, data: any) {
   let search = data.filter((indivitem: object) => {
       if(indivitem["name"] === term) {
         return indivitem;
       }
   }
   console.log("searchResults", search);
}
```

I need advice on how to use my `searchColumnOnlyArray` to only search values in those keys. Advice on how I can constrain my filter to look/search values using the set keys in `searchColumnOnlyArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method for each individual item within your [filter callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Parameters). With the `.some()` method, you can iterate through your columns array and return `true` when one of the given column values (ie: keys) holds a value which matches your search term. If your `.some()` callback never returns true, and `false` for every column item/key, then the result of calling `.some()` will be false, which will result in the filter method not keeping the item in the final resulting array:

```js
const data = [ { name: "Janet McKenly", age: 49, city: "Baltimore", active: "2019-02-15", role: "Admin. Assistant" }, { name: "Eric Brown", age: 23, city: "Dallas", active: "2020-06-01", role: "Janitor" }, { name: "Nora Payne", age: 41, city: "Los Angeles", active: "2020-10-02", role: "Sales Associate" } ];

const searchColumnOnlyArray = ["name", "city", "active"];
const term = "Dallas";
const search = data.filter(item =>
  searchColumnOnlyArray.some(col => item[col] === term)
);
console.log("searchResults", search);
```

Note: In your example, you are returning the item which you want to keep in the filter method, while this works, it's not how you should be using `.filter()`. Your callback should be returning true/false (or a truthy/falsy value). When you return true, the current item is kept in the resulting array returned by `.filter()`, if you return `false` then it is not kept in the resulting arrray.

Answer (score 1):

```
data.forEach(ele => {
   searchColumnOnlyArray.forEach( search => {
       console.log(ele[search]);
   });
});
```

I can't try the code right now but this should do the job